# Ask user if external link should be opened in an external window / tab

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript running on my site to open all external links in a new window / tab:

```
function linkopener(a) {
    var b = a ? "_blank" : "_self";
    var c = document.links;
    for (var i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
      if (c[i].href.search("domain.tld") == -1) c[i].target = b;
    }
}
window.onload = linkopener;
```

Now I would like to add a question to the user as soon as she/he clicks on an external link whether she/he wants to open it in a new window/tab or open it in the current window/tab.
No question should be shown if she/he wants to exit the site manually.
Is that possible and if yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function linkopener(a) {
    var b = a ? "_blank" : "_self";
    var c = document.links;
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].href.search("peleke.de") == -1) {
            c[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                if (confirm("Do you want to open this in a new window/tab?")) {
                    this.target = b;
                } else {
                    this.target = '';
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
window.onload = linkopener;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/D2JES/7/show)

Comment: When I add it to a JQuery 
`$(document).ready(function(){
 linkopener();
});`
it always opens in the same window/tab no matter if I press on OK or Cancel

Comment: Because you're not passing anything for the `a` argument, which is used to set `b`. With `window.onload = linkopener`, the argument is the load event.

Comment: BTW, you should come up with more meaningful variable names than `a`, `b`, and `c`.